# array of images in document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I have select multiple images from iPhone through ELC controller. The images are stored in array now I want to store this array of images in document directory so please help me someone..

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)]){
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

for (UIView *v in [_scrollView subviews]) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}

CGRect workingFrame = _scrollView.frame;
workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];


for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {

    UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [images addObject:image];

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    imageview.frame = workingFrame;

    [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];
    [imageview release];

    workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
}

self.chosenImages = images;
NSLog(@"values=%@",_chosenImages);

[_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: How have you tried saving them and what didn't work?

Comment: sir i have no idea to save the array at a time i have just add one image at a time

Comment: Presumably you want to save each image as an individual file in a specified folder?

Comment: yes ofcourse you get my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For each of the images in the `images` array, write to the file file one by one.

   ```
   NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

   NSInteger anIndex = 0;
   for (UIImage *anImage in images) {
      NSString *anImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", anIndex++];
      NSString *anImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", aDocumentsDirectory, anImageName];

      NSData *anImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(anImage);
     [anImageData writeToFile:anImagePath atomically:YES];
   }
   ```

---

2.. When you extract the Original Image, save image to file right there.

```
    NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSInteger anIndex = 0;

    for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {
       UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
       [images addObject:image];

       UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
       [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
       imageview.frame = workingFrame;

       [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];
       [imageview release];

       workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;

       // Save Image
       NSString *anImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", anIndex++];
       NSString *anImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", aDocumentsDirectory, anImageName];

       NSData *anImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
       [anImageData writeToFile:anImagePath atomically:YES];
}
```